# Pi 4 hangs often; only power cycle brings it back

Tags: pi-4

I've got a Raspberry Pi 4 that keeps hanging. It becomes completely unresponsive and I have to physically power-cycle the Pi to get it to respond again. I could be wrong, but I have observed that it tends to happen when it's under higher load.

Among other things, I have PiHole running in Docker. I've noticed that shortly after accessing the admin portal of PiHole, the Pi often becomes unresponsive. The same thing often happens if I run re-pull and re-create my Docker containers. I've moved as many services off the Pi as I can, including PiHole, but the hanging issue does still occasionally happen.

Thinking it could be a power supply issue, I recently bought some 40W chargers. Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. I've checked `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure temp` and it tends to sit around 40-45°C and up to maybe 48°C when under heavy load. I also checked `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd get_throttled` and it gave `0x0` which I believe means the voltage and temperature are both ok.

I had 2 terminals open to the Pi overnight to see if there are any clues. One shows the temperature and one shows `htop`. Both looked normal at the moment the terminals disconnected. One showed 46°C and the other showed average of 27.2% CPU, 524M/7.69G memory, and 0K/2.00G swap. No unusual processes that I can see.

I'm at a loss as to how to diagnose this any further. But since this Pi does some fairly critical things like reverse proxy and authentication/authorisation to my services, I would really prefer if it didn't go down all the time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Running out of memory can cause linux to lock up solid.  Sometimes enabling OOM kill helps, but not always.   If accessing the docker image caused sudden memory use, htop might not catch it before the system locks up.

Comment: Have a look at the [load average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)); this is a decisive way to rule out (or confirm) processor load as the issue.  From your description, memory is unlikely to be the cause.  WRT "I recently bought some 40W chargers", check the logs for `Under-voltage detected!`, and note that chargers for mobile devices with onboard batteries do not make ideal primary power supplies for live devices with no battery.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem as well. Therefore I´ve following reasons which has resolved my issue and could be helpful for you as well:

1. Latest Kernel update (If you have made any updates try a rollback first)
2. Docker Container Ressource mismanagement and misconfiguration run

> docker stats
> [image]
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/

to check you ressource limits inside of the container my issue was that the allocated Memory could never retrieved which resulted into those hangings as well

3. Old SD-Card

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem. I have multiple docker containers running on my pi such as pihole, a proxy server, wireguard and a few more personal services I created. As long as I don't touch any container my raspberry pi works like a charm. However, when e.g. redeploying a container, it often hangs the whole pi, as you already described.

I have not yet found out why this happens, one assumption I have, is that it could be due to the micro SD card, which is by no means a perfect place for an OS. I am going to replace the SD card with a m.2 SSD in the near future, see https://blog.mivia.dk/solved-sd-card-corrupted-raspberry-pi/. I guess that could be worth a try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any update on this ? have you tried ssd ?

Comment: Yes indeed. I switched to a ssd about 10 months ago and it did not hang a single time since. But in hindsight it was probably a faulty sd card because many colleges reported to me that their pi, running with a sd cars, also doesn’t hang.